# adding linked entities?

Tags: linq, entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1

I have an `Apple` entity where it contains an incrementing identity field.

```
Owner owner = new Owner();
Apple apple = new Apple();
DbContext.Apple.Add(apple);
Owner.Apple = apple;
DbContext.Owner.Add(owner);
DbContext.SaveChanges();
```

Would the above code correctly link two entities together while both inserting into the database?

I'm guessing this has something to do with Delayed Execution, but I am still very blurred on this concept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign the Apple to your owner, insert the owner in your database, and then they will both get inserted (with a relationship between the two).

So just like this:

```
Owner owner = new Owner();
Apple apple = new Apple();
Owner.Apple = apple;
DbContext.Owner.Add(owner);
DbContext.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: cool thanks for the quick response! in this example `apple` is a new entity added to `owner`, now what if `apple` is an existing entity? would EF simply link to the existing one or would it create a duplicated entity?

Comment: If change tracking is enabled on your entity (which it is by default, if you retrieve the Apple from your database), entity framework will find out that it's an existing entity and will just perform an update.